# Can search engines crawl all the information on pages using endless scrolling with jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm interested in the idea of setting up a gallery of hundreds beautiful images I've collected across Hawaii using a page that uses endless paging of some sort. Each will have a description, a background story, h2 title, etc. I will be using php as my back-end language.

Will search engines be able to crawl all the images/text using this method?

Can you suggest some plugins that have been created that are worth checking out for endless paging?

I'd like to be able to add scroll to anchor tags on this page. Using the below code will it still function properly for anchor tags that are created using endless scrolling?

```
//Direct link scrolls to anchor tag
URL: example.com/gallery#mountain
<a name="mountain"><img /></a>
```

Comment: I find your question hard to answer: title "can search engines crawl?" vs. content "can searach engines ... + is there any plugin?". You'll definitively need a backend, so you should add the backend technology used (or tell us if you expect to make this possible without a backend - just pure webhosting/nginx/apache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search engines will crawl and index your content if you have a good SEO setup, like `title` and `alt` attributes in your images tags, a `title`, `description`, relevant `keywords` in the `head` of your HTML document.
See here for more detailed info on SEO:
[here](http://diythemes.com/thesis/wordpress-seo-image-optimization/) and [here](http://blog.raventools.com/anatomy-of-a-search-optimized-photo-gallery/)

For a quick infinite gallery plugin solution you can check any of these solutions:
[least](http://kamilczujowski.github.io/least/), [photoset-grid](http://stylehatch.github.io/photoset-grid/), [wowslider](http://wowslider.com/), [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

If you opt by having all the photos being displayed in one page like a big pile, i suggest you add lazy loading functionality, this way the images will load only when the user is scrolling down, and not load all at once when the page opens, which would be a massive loading time because such amount of images.